# Digital signature on Local IIS vs IIS Express

Tags: iis, cryptography, devexpress, digital-signature, iis-express

I have a problem with my ASP.Net webForms application for digitally signing documents using DevExpress libraries.
When I host the application via Local IIS, an exception pops up: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. And inner exception: invalid flags.
But when I host the application on IIS Express, the application works normally.
I contacted Devexpress support.
They told me: It turns out that issue are not directly related to our components. To sign a document, we use the standard System.Security.Cryptography namespace. As I see, the exception is thrown from these classes. I searched the Internet and found several similar issues related to IIS and System.Security.Cryptography.
But I still couldn't figure out the problem.
But the exception occurs at the moment when the dialog for entering the pin should be opened.

I assume that some permissions are in question or some configuration, please help.
Here is the code:

```
public bool signPdf(X509Certificate2 selectedCertificate, string locationParam, string contactInfoParam, string reasonParam, string sourcePath, string destPath)
        {
            try
            {
                string PomName = "";
                string PomGreska = "";
                string sourcePathFixed = Razno.FixPath(sourcePath);
                string destPathFixed = Razno.FixPath(destPath);

                Stream inter = new MemoryStream();

                using (var signer = new PdfDocumentSigner(sourcePathFixed))
                {
                    HashAlgorithmType hashAlgorithmToBeUsed = HashAlgorithmType.SHA256;

                    switch (selectedCertificate.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName.ToUpper())
                    {
                        case "SHA1RSA":
                            hashAlgorithmToBeUsed = HashAlgorithmType.SHA1;
                            break;
                        case "SHA256RSA":
                            hashAlgorithmToBeUsed = HashAlgorithmType.SHA256;
                            break;
                        case "SHA384RSA":
                            hashAlgorithmToBeUsed = HashAlgorithmType.SHA384;
                            break;
                        case "SHA512RSA":
                            hashAlgorithmToBeUsed = HashAlgorithmType.SHA512;
                            break;
                        default:
                            hashAlgorithmToBeUsed = HashAlgorithmType.SHA256;
                            break;
                    }

                    Pkcs7Signer pkcs7Signature = new Pkcs7Signer(selectedCertificate, hashAlgorithmToBeUsed, null, null, null, PdfSignatureProfile.PAdES_BES);
                    var newSignature = new PdfSignatureBuilder(pkcs7Signature);

                    Sertifikati s = new Sertifikati();
                    newSignature.Location = s.GetLocationFromSubject(selectedCertificate.Subject);
                    newSignature.Name = s.GetContactInfoFromSubject(selectedCertificate.Subject);
                    newSignature.Reason = reasonParam;
                    Sertifikati.SubjectNameFromCert(selectedCertificate, ref PomName, ref PomGreska);

                    string contactInfoValue = contactInfoParam;
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(contactInfoValue)) contactInfoValue = PomName;
                    newSignature.ContactInfo = contactInfoValue;
                    signer.SaveDocument(inter, newSignature);
                }

                using (var fileStream = File.Create(destPathFixed))
                {
                    inter.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    inter.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                EventLogManager.WriteToEventLogInformation("DigitalSignature", "Application", "Errir ih method signPdfWithoutTimestamp : " + e.Message);
                return false;
            }

        }
```

```
Exception.Message:
 Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Exception.StackTrace:
  at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at DevExpress.Pdf.Pkcs7Signer.RSACngSignatureHelper.SignDigest(Byte[] digest)
   at DevExpress.Pdf.Pkcs7SignerBase.CreateSignature(Byte[] dataDigest, String hashOid)
   at DevExpress.Pdf.Native.DocumentSigning.PdfSignatureModelObject.PatchStream(PdfBinaryWriter writer, Boolean resetGeneration)
   at DevExpress.Pdf.PdfDocumentSigner.SaveDocument(Stream stream, PdfSignatureBuilder[] signatures)
   at Osa.Unidocs.ElektronskiPotpisStandardModul.PdfDevExpressSigning.signPdf(X509Certificate2 selectedCertificate, String locationParam, String contactInfoParam, String reasonParam, String sourcePath, String destPath) 

Exception.Source:
  mscorlib

Exception.InnerException.Message:
 Invalid flags.

Exception.InnerException.StackTrace:
   at System.Security.Cryptography.NCryptNative.SignHash[T](SafeNCryptKeyHandle key, Byte[] hash, T& paddingInfo, AsymmetricPaddingMode paddingMode, NCryptHashSigner`1 signer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.NCryptNative.SignHashPkcs1(SafeNCryptKeyHandle key, Byte[] hash, String hashAlgorithm)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.SignHash(Byte[] hash, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding)

Exception.InnerException.Source:
  System.Core
```

Comment: You will have to ask DevExpress support if their code was ever tested and fully supported on IIS. And if so, what extra steps you need to configure. Your code works differently on IIS and Visual Studio/IIS Express, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 So things can easily break.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for your reply.
I contacted Devexpress support, who said that the problem is not directly related to them, that they use the standard System.Security.Cryptography namespace. They also added that they searched the internet and saw several similar issues related to IIS and System.Security.Cryptography. And that I can manually search for a suitable solution on the Internet or refer to general programming forums, such as Stack Overflow, which I actually did.